# How to stop a loop when clicking asynchronously in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, xpath, casperjs

I'm crawling multiple pages using CasperJS, but I got stuck.

The maximum number of pages are 200 but I want to stop the execution if the XPath below doesn't exist (for a page before the 200th).

How can I set up `i` variable?

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

for (var i=1; i <=200; i++) {
    casper.wait(6000, function() {

        casper.thenClick(x('//*[@id="mArticle"]/div[2]/a['+i+']'), function (){
            console.log('Searching dic');
            words = words.concat(this.evaluate(getWords));
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: you can escape the loop with `break;`

Comment: @DanielCheung where would you put it?

Comment: Apart from inventing a time machine, you can't stop the loop because it has already run 6 seconds ago. You need to re-think the logic.

Comment: You put that in an if-statement?

Comment: @DanielCheung where exactly would you put it? Are you aware that the main logic runs asynchronously?

Comment: I'm the man who wrote question, and I'd like to know how to write "if statement" that could check whether "'//*[@id="mArticle"]/div[2]/a['+i+']'exist or not?" (last page or not?)

Comment: what does x() return if xpath "fails"

Comment: when fail, error message is like this :
CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: xpath selector: //*[@id="mArticle"]/div[2]/a[4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasperJS provides the [`exists()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#exists) function. So, you can rewrite your code like this:

```js
for (var i=1; i <=200; i++) {
    (function(i){
        casper.wait(6000, function() {
            var button = x('//*[@id="mArticle"]/div[2]/a['+i+']');
            if (!this.exists(button)) {
                this.echo(i + " not available");
                return; // the following `thenClick()` is not executed
            }
            this.thenClick(button, function (){
                console.log('Searching dic');
                words = words.concat(this.evaluate(getWords));
            });
        });
    })(i);
}
```

I've also added an IIFE, so that you have the correct `i` inside of the callback. For more information, see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1816580).

This works, but it is not very efficient if one would assume that if link 100 is not there, then link 101 and 102 etc. are also not there. You would wait a lot (6 seconds times 100). In that case you need to do this recursively, because of the asynchronous nature of CasperJS:

```js
function execOnce(casper, i, max){
    // end condition
    if (i === max) {
        return;
    }
    casper.wait(6000, function() {
        var button = x('//*[@id="mArticle"]/div[2]/a['+i+']');
        if (!this.exists(button)) {
            this.echo(i + " not available");
            return;
        }
        this.thenClick(button, function (){
            console.log('Searching dic');
            words = words.concat(this.evaluate(getWords));

            // recursive step
            execOnce(this, i+1, max);
        });
    });
};

casper.start(url);

// start the recursive chain
casper.then(function(){
    execOnce(this, 1, 200);
});

casper.run();
```

Note that now that you have it recursively, you can define a proper end condition by explicitly looking on the page what's there and what isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got this and I noticed that you miss "else" under the if state ment  but I really apprecitated

Comment: The missing `else` was deliberate, because I want to reduce nesting of JavaScript callbacks, but I indeed forgot the `return` statement.

Comment: I really appreciate if you read my Question2...(Edited Question)

Comment: The answer is already big as it is and I don't understand what you're asking there. Please don't edit your questions to ask followup questions when there are already answers. You can post a new question with a complete description of your issue and what you want to accomplish. Then you can include a link to the previous question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll remember your advice. I'm new at this service. I'll make a new question :)

Comment: I wrote new question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426015/is-it-possible-to-make-for-loop-in-casperjs